# Robo3T connect to remote Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, vps, robo3t

I rent a google cloud VPS server, on which I install MongoDB and Nodejs server (Expressjs) connect to it with localhost: 27017, it's ok but how to connect Robo3t on my personal computer to that database.
Please help, thank you!

Comment: You can configure an SSH tunnel in the connection. And then use localhost like you did before.

Comment: I connected to the VPS server via SSH on port 22, your mean is that I can connect to MongoDB via SSH right? Please give me a tutorial link if you have. Thank you for your answer

Comment: https://medium.com/faun/ssh-tunneling-in-robo-3t-to-mongodb-runs-on-aws-ec2-1870c21e6180